# Expectation value of empiric copula

Tags: expectation

I need the expected value of the [empirical copula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)#Empirical_copulas).

I have for a fix $\mathbf{u}=(u_1,\dots,u_d) \in [0,1]^d$

$\mathbb{E}[C^n(\mathbf{u})] = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}(\tilde{U}_1^i \le u_1,\dots,\tilde{U}_d^i \le u_d)] $

Then

$\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}(\tilde{U}_1^i \le u_1,\dots,\tilde{U}_d^i \le u_d)] = \mathbb{P}(\tilde{U}_1^i \le u_1,\dots,\tilde{U}_d^i \le u_d) = \mathbb{P}(F^n_1(X^i_1) \le u_1,\dots,F^n_d(X^i_d) \le u_d)$

Now I stuck here and can't see how to get a good result.

Any idea?

With best regards

Fluffy